# random move tic tac toe in c

Tags: c, arrays, random, tic-tac-toe

alright, so I'm really new at coding in C and I have a LOT of copy and paste in my code. (it's my final project, so I really don't have time to optimize and shorten until the end if time permits). So anyway, I'm gonna avoid posting all my code for that reason. I'm only gonna post the relevant part which is what I'm trying to do.

I need the game to pick a random number from 1-9 and then use that number to select a move on the board. I added a printf in this part of the code to make sure a number is being picked, but then when i go to scanf, the game just gives a blinking prompt and does not continue.

Does anyone see what is wrong or do i need to post any other section of code? Any help will be really appreciated!! I have only included the 1 player portion of the game and then when the computer is supposed to move. I removed the win checks and the re printing of the board. Let me know if you guys need to see anything else i just didn't want to have a huge block of code.

```
if (player == 1)
    {
        for(k=0;k<9;k++) // 9 moves max.
        {
        printf("\n\n"); // print board again.
        printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
        printf("---+---+---\n");
        printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
        printf("---+---+---\n");
        printf(" %c | %c | %c\n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);

        do
        {
            printf("Player 1, where would you like to move? Enter 1-9\n");
            scanf("%d", &move);

            if (move == 1)
                board[0][0] = '1';
            if (move == 2)
                board[0][1] = '1';
            if (move == 3)
                board[0][2] = '1';
            if (move == 4)
                board[1][0] = '1';
            if (move == 5)
                board[1][1] = '1';
            if (move == 6)
                board[1][2] = '1';
            if (move == 7)
                board[2][0] = '1';
            if (move == 8)
                board[2][1] = '1';
            if (move == 9)
                board[2][2] = '1';

        }while(move>9 && move <1);


        do
        {
            printf("Computer moves...");


            move = rand() % 9 + 1;
            printf("%d", move);
            scanf("%d", &move);


            if (move == 1)
                board[0][0] = '2';
            if (move == 2)
                board[0][1] = '2';
            if (move == 3)
                board[0][2] = '2';
            if (move == 4)
                board[1][0] = '2';
            if (move == 5)
                board[1][1] = '2';
            if (move == 6)
                board[1][2] = '2';
            if (move == 7)
                board[2][0] = '2';
            if (move == 8)
                board[2][1] = '2';
            if (move == 9)
                board[2][2] = '2';


        }while(move>9 && move <1);



    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting `scanf()` to do?

Comment: scan the random number picked by the computer? When I did this with the human part, it works. But when I use rand to pick the number, it sees scanf does not?

Comment: @GabriellaCoronell Afaik (I don't know c), `scanf` requests input from the console, not any arbitrary source.

Comment: Note: For your first move there are 9 empty squares so you want a random number from 0 to 8. For your second move 2 squares have already become occupied and there's only 7 empty squares, so you want a random number from 0 to 6. For your fifth move there will only be 1 empty square left, so you don't need a random number at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to reamove `scanf()` from your code, `scanf()` blocks until input is given to the program, it returns the number of items that matched the format string if any, by the input.

If you are generating the number with `rand()` then you don't need any input at all.

Please read [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), to understand what `scanf()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`move = rand () % 9;`

to avoid this.

Comment: That seems like a comment rather than an answer. Please edit your question to give a better explanation, suggestion like answers should be given in comment section.